# My Session is getting auto cleared after i receive a get request from paypal in django

Tags: python, django, session, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using paypalrestsdk for accepting payments

```
def process_subscription(request, subscription_type):
    print(request.session.load()) # output : {'name': 'Abhay', 'password': 'k2jk2332k'}
    # code to process payment
    if payment.success()
       return redirect(redirect_url)
    return redirect(reverse('error_page'))

@csrf_exempt
def success(request):
    print(request.session.load()) # here output is {} blank
    return render(request, 'success.html')
```

It don't works even if i have removed @csrf_exempt, i have searched on google but did'nt found solution to it...

But when i visit url of success() then it works

Django Version : 3.2
PaypalRestSdk version : 1.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PayPal REST SDK is deprecated and implements an older version of subscriptions that you should not be using. It is not compatible with the current PayPal Subscriptions.

The current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) does not have any SDK support, and does not use redirects if you integrate with its button.